# Select by grouped rows and order by date

Tags: mysql-5.5, group-by

I have a table liked this:

```
session | created_at          | data
------------------------------------
12345   | 2018-10-10 08:10:10 | {}
13456   | 2018-10-11 09:12:13 | {}
12345   | 2018-10-10 08:12:13 | {}
14567   | 2018-08-09 10:11:12 | {}
14567   | 2018-08-09 03:09:11 | {}
12345   | 2018-10-10 08:24:12 | {}
```

There are thousands of rows. I'd like to group the rows by session but also order each group by timestamp. So if a new item is added to an existing session, that session group would be at the top.

I'd like to LIMIT this by groups of sessions. So ultimately I'd like to select groups of sessions and limit by group. This way, if I limit by 10, I'd potentially get 35 rows that comprises the 10 sessions.

Simply grouping by session, doesn't show all the rows, but 1 row per session. So this output I'd like to have like:

```
session | created_at          | data
------------------------------------
14567   | 2018-12-09 10:11:12 | {}
14567   | 2018-08-09 03:09:11 | {}
------------------------------------
13456   | 2018-10-11 09:12:18 | {}
13456   | 2018-10-11 09:12:13 | {}
------------------------------------
12345   | 2018-10-10 08:24:12 | {}
12345   | 2018-10-10 08:12:13 | {}
12345   | 2018-10-10 08:10:10 | {}
```

Comment: Where this row `13456   | 2018-10-11 09:12:18 | {}` comes from?

Comment: And please, tag your DBMS (version included)

Comment: `select * from tablename order by session desc, created_at desc ;` ...?

Comment: @McNets I must have added it when building the second layout. I'll edit it to match the first set.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ This does what I need, but the LIMIT part is an issue. If I LIMIT 10, I will only get 10 records, but I actually want 10 sessions. Maybe that was not as clear in the question.

Comment: All data from 10 sessions? If yes, which 10?

Comment: `select t.* from tablename as t join (select session from tablename group by session order by <whatever> limit 10) as s using (session) order by t.session desc, t.created_at desc ;`

Comment: The last 10 most recent sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t1.*
from table t1
          join (select t2.session, max(t2.created_at) max_created_at
                from table t2
                group by t2.session
                order by max_created_at desc
                limit 10 
               ) t3
          on t1.session = t3.session
order by t3.max_created_at desc, t3.session ;
```

Comment: This is the output I am looking for. Is there a way to LIMIT the number of sessions found? Not just limit rows returned, but limit grouped sessions?

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you both for your time on this one. Huge appreciation!